# Retrieve queue items from specific partition or group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant solution where jobs are submitted from an on-premise system for background processing. Once the result is available, my design is to write a poller from on-premise system which will take the results and send it to the original requester.

My solution runs on `AWS` and I was planning to use `SQS` to store the results once available. The poller will dequeue an item from this queue and if for some reason poller goes down `visibility timeout` of the queue ensures that result is not lost.

However, since my solution is a multi-tenant one how can I ensure that a on-premise poller gets only the result of that tenant. If I have a single SQS then poller will get a random result of some other tenant. I know that SQS does have a concept of group ids but there is no provision for a poller to query based on a group id.

I would like to avoid creating a `SQS` per tenant. Is there any better solution for this? Note that my solution is `AWS` specific and need not be portable to other cloud vendors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQS queue per tenant is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to selectively pull messages from an Amazon SQS queue.

The `MessageGroupId` you mention is specific to FIFO queues and simply ensures that messages with the same Group ID are delivered in-order. It is not related to the ability to pull a specific subset of messages.

You will either need separate queues per tenant, or a polling mechanism that works for *all* tenants.